Laravel vue3 meta tag layout not loading
this is my routes file
const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'home',
        component: Home,
        meta: {
            layout: 'home',
            pageTitle: TITLE.HOME_PAGE_TITLE,
        },
    }
]

this is my router index file
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";
import AuthRoutes from "./AuthRoutes";
import TITLE from '../utilities/PageTitles';
import routes from "./AllRoutes";
const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes,
});

export default router;


this is my app.js
import "./bootstrap";

import router from "./routes/index";
import AuthService from "./services/AuthService";
import store from "./store";
import { onMounted, onBeforeUnmount, ref, createApp } from 'vue';
import Home from './layouts/Home.vue';

const app = createApp({
    setup() {
        const layout = ref('loading');

        const setLayout = (source, newLayout) => {
            console.log(source, newLayout,'source new layout');
            let exLayout = layout.value;
            layout.value = newLayout || router.currentRoute.value.meta.layout || 'loading';

            if (exLayout !== layout.value && layout.value === 'default') {
                if (AuthService.authToken()) {
                    getLoggedInUser() // To refresh user data in local storage on page reload
                        .then()
                        .catch();
                }

                getGeneralLookupData();
            }
        };

        const getLoggedInUser = async () => {
            // Your logic to get logged in user
            await store.dispatch('Login/getLoggedInUser');
        };

        const getGeneralLookupData = async () => {
            // Your logic to get general lookup data
            await store.dispatch('General/getGeneralLookupData');
        };

        onMounted(() => {
            EventBus.on('layout', (value) => {
                setLayout('event', value);
            });
        });

        onBeforeUnmount(() => {
            EventBus.off('layout');
        });

        return {
            layout,
            setLayout,
            getLoggedInUser,
            getGeneralLookupData
        };
    },
});


app.use(router);
app.use(store);
app.component('home', Home);
app.component('auth', Auth);
app.mount("#app");

export default app;


I am trying to load the layout I have try to change the routes file and change the json structure but nothing works layout is not loading
I am not sure why layout is not loading I am converting vue from vue2 to vue3 in laravel 10 layout was loading in vue2 can you help me with this what is the issue

Does router.currentRoute have a value? Do a console.log of it inside setup() method

Yes I am getting object with bunch of information when I console.log router.currentRoute
deep
_rawValue
_value
In _value I have
fullPath
hash
href
matched: []
meta
{layout: 'default', pageTitle: 'Dashboard'}
...
